# Creating a table for indexing another table

Tags: mysql, index

We have a table with 350m rows and 12 columns, and around 1m rows adding everyday. We have crappy hardware and we cannot add an index on one of the 12 columns that we really really need to. (severe lack of use case analysis)

We have tried adding an index on a less busy and less crowded (14m rows) table via percona toolkit , but it didn't work either , failing in 12 hours , due to hardware sloppiness. So we are not gonna try it on the 350m table at all.

I guess the only solution left is creating another table , just for indexing the column on the 350m-row table.

Is this convenient ? is there any other solution you may suggest ?

We have this problem with many tables and a solid solution would make my life easier.

Comment: Sounds to me like you have several problems which you need to address. I wouldn't create another table as that will be adding yet another problem.

Comment: well , i have to use a query that needs an index on the column X , redesign is not an option because we cannot alter crowded tables

Comment: I would very strongly suggest upgrading your hardware and investigate migrating to a DBMS that doesn't have these concurrency and scalability issues. I would suggest PostgreSQL.

Comment: thank you for the nice suggestions but once again , i'm here because those suggestions are not an option

Comment: It sounds to me like you need partitioning, too.

Comment: you should update the question with table structure, sample query and sample results. there are many guys around here who might be able to help but doesn't bother because of lack of information.

Comment: thank you , but i just believe that my question is regardless from table structure or query sample